# Upload non-text file to sharepoint REST api from php

Tags: rest, php

I am using Php curl to upload file to sharepoint api.  I am able to successfully upload a text file using sharepoint rest api. However, when non-text files are uploaded, the file actually is uploaded with the correct size etc but the contents look corrupted and not displaying.

In the below code, the $digest value is got correctly from sharepoint contextinfo url (not shown in this code)

Any thoughts?

```
$url = "http://mysharepointurl/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/<Folder Name>')/Files/Add(url='" . $name . "',overwrite=true)";

   $mimeType = "image/jpeg"; // different for pdf and text etc.
   $filename = "icon.jpg"
   $filepath = "c:\\icon.jpg";
   $cfile = getCurlValue($filepath,$mime,$filename);         
   $data = array('file' => $cfile); 

    $ch = curl_init();        
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $login);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH,  CURLAUTH_BASIC);   
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array("Accept: application/json;odata=verbose","Content-length:$filesize", "Content-type:$mimeType", "X-RequestDigest:$digest","binaryStringRequestBody:true","X-HTTP-Method:MERGE"));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); 
    $chresult = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);    
    $resultsJSON = json_decode($chresult, true);
    $results = json_encode($resultsJSON, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) ;     
    echo "<pre>" . $results . "</pre>";  

  function getCurlValue($filename, $contentType, $postname)
{
    // PHP 5.5 introduced a CurlFile object that deprecates the old @filename syntax
    // See: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/curl-file-upload
    if (function_exists('curl_file_create')) {
        return curl_file_create($filename, $contentType, $postname);
    }

    // Use the old style if using an older version of PHP
    $value = "@{$this->filename};filename=" . $postname;
    if ($contentType) {
        $value .= ';type=' . $contentType;
    }

    return $value;
}
```

Comment: did you resolve this? I am currently using your code to test uploading files to sharepoint.

Comment: @wayzz did u find solution

Answer (score 2):

I know this may have been abandoned but I am still leaving this answer here just in case anyone is trying out this code.

Using the above code the contents of the file is not sent through with the request and when the file is created/updated the contents of the file will be replaced with the `boundary` parameter created by the `Content-Type` header.

The change I did to this code was append the contents of the file to the `Content-Type` after the `$mimType` variable like so :

```
Content-Type:$mimeType\r\n\r\n".file_get_contents($filepath)
```

The result of the POST headers are as such :

```
Content-Type:text/plain testddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd; boundary=------------------------04414062f2c8e909
```

This was also tested using a `pdf` file and was successful.